# Cross-compile java applications

Tags: java, openwrt, cross-compiling

I am working on an embedded system with openwrt root files system and linux kernel.

I have compiled the trunk, no problem with that. I have installed the Java resources in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/share`, but I haven't been able to compile some simple programs that I have done in Eclipse. I have used `javac` to compile a hello world and I obtain the .class file but when I try to execute the helloworld.class file in my embedded system with:

```
java helloworld.class
```

it does nothing, it just says:

```
/usr/bin/java: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
```

When I execute this in my computer it runs, so I guess it is because I have to cross-compile the java files, so how can I do that?

Comment: You don't cross-compile Java since Java runs in a vm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your class, but with a syntax error in the /usr/bin/java script - try cat /usr/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

Just try the java command withoud .class extension like

```
java helloworld
```